# Position: sticky по отношению к родительским div-ам

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Подскажите, можно ли зафиксировать `div` (`blog_portfolio_nav`) при скролле (с отступом `top: 20px;`)? Скроллиться должно по отношению к `div` с текстом (`blog_portfolio_text`), а на шапку и футер не должно забегать. Прочитала кучу статей: пробовала и `position: sticky;` и `position: fixed;`, так же встречала громоздкие плагины... но ничего не выходит. Может кто знает простое решение на `javascript`?

```css
.footer,
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  background: #92ff92;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  height: 880px;
}

.blog_portfolio_content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.blog_portfolio_nav a {
  display: block;
}

.blog_portfolio_nav {
  width: 30%;
}

.blog_portfolio_text {
  width: 67%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Шапка</div>

<div class="blog_portfolio_content">

  <div class="blog_portfolio_nav">
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  </div>

  <div class="blog_portfolio_text">
    Текст... текст... Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст...
    текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст...
    текст... Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст...
    текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст...
    текст... Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст...
    текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...
  </div>

</div>

<div class="footer">Подвал</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде получилось без JavaScript-а)

```css
.footer,
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  background: #92ff92;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  height: 880px;
}

.blog_portfolio_content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.blog_portfolio_nav a {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
}

.blog_portfolio_nav {
  width: 30%;
}

.blog_portfolio_text {
  width: 67%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Шапка</div>

<div class="blog_portfolio_content">

  <div class="blog_portfolio_nav">
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="blog_portfolio_text">
  
    Текст... текст... Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст...
    текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст...
    текст... Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст...
    текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст...
    текст... Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст...
    текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...Текст... текст...
  </div>

</div>

<div class="footer">Подвал</div>
```

Comment: У меня на сайте не работает... Не понимаю...

Comment: Не работало из-за класса для модальных окон, когда включались модальные окна подставлялся класс 'overflow: auto !important;'